# Hibernate - Unable to load class declared

Tags: java, hibernate

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь написать свой первый сайт с этого примера https://habrahabr.ru/post/111102/
но у меня возникает ошибка вот мой StackTrace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/data.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to load class declared as <mapping class="net.schastny.contactmanager.domain.Contact"/> in the configuration:
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
... 24 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to load class declared as <mapping class="net.schastny.contactmanager.domain.Contact"/> in the configuration:
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.parseMappingElement(AnnotationConfiguration.java:638)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1561)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1540)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:1002)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:69)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1514)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:990)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:69)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1449)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:978)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:69)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:642)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.schastny.contactmanager.domain.Contact
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:100)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.parseMappingElement(AnnotationConfiguration.java:635)
```

data.xml

```
 <bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"/>

    <property name="configurationClass">
        <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
    <hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <mapping class="net.schastny.contactmanager.domain.Contact"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Contact.java

```
 package net.schastny.contactmanager.domain;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "CONTACTS")
public class Contact {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "FIRSTNAME")
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name = "LASTNAME")
    private String lastname;

    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "TELEPHONE")
    private String telephone;

    // Getters and setters

}
```

Подскажите в чем проблема, что не так?

Comment: Что насчёт класса net.schastny.contactmanager.domain.Contact? Он добавлен в Ваш проект? Стоит внимательнее относится к последней причине исключения.

Comment: @ВикторБоровлёв вот, посмотрите добавил класс Contact

Comment: Извините за глупый вопрос. Геттеры и Сеттеры реализованы в классе Contact или так и оставлен один комментарий?

Comment: Проверьте файл `hibernate.cfg.xml` , в нем не закрыт тег `<property>`

Comment: @MrFylypenko извините, это опечатка.

Comment: @ВикторБоровлёв реализованы)